# How to fix Google Script/HTML Form not submitting for all authorised editors

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am building a rota, which has three separate functions:

-Adding a staff member
-Editing staff details
-Removing a staff member

Each script triggers an HTML form which needs to be filled in and on submission the form is processed to update the rota across multiple tabs.

The scripts all work as intended for me.  I have shared this in with select other users and ensured that they have all run the script through the script editor and allowed authorization.

The problem faced is two-fold.  For some users, everything works fine.  For some users, some of the scripts work but not all.  For one user, none of the scripts work.

It appears that for those which are not working, after submitting the form the script which processes it is not being triggered at all.

I am not particularly proficient with coding, so imagine the problem is somewhere in the script itself, but I am honestly bamboozled by it working to different degrees for different people!

Below is a snippet of the Google Script and HTML.  I've removed a lot of the actual processing from the .gs, as the issue appears to be with the function (addForm) triggering.

I have tried having all scripts in 1 single file on the project.  I have tried having all scripts contained in their own script file within the project (e.g - the project had 1 script for the menu bar, then 1 script for each function, and 1 HTML file for each function - a total of 4 scripts and 3 HTML files in 1 project).  I have also tried a bastardisation of both options.  All to no avail.

AddScript.gs:

```
function addDialogue() {
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('AddHTML')
        .setTitle('Add New Staff')
        .setWidth(500)
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

function addForm(formObject) {
    var parent = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getParent();
    var landing = parent.getSheetByName("Landing Page");
    var data = parent.getSheetByName("Data");
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var PP = formObject.PP;
    var dept = formObject.dept;
    data.getRange("A20").setValue(PP);
    data.getRange("A21").setValue(dept);
}
```

AddHTML.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
    <font face="courier">
        <form id="AddForm"
            onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); google.script.run.addForm(this); google.script.host.close()">
            <br>
            Starting PP:<br>
            <select name="PP">
                <option value="PP8">PP8</option>
                <option value="PP9">PP9</option>
                <option value="PP10">PP10</option>
                <option value="PP11">PP11</option>
                <option value="PP12">PP12</option>
                <option value="PP13">PP13</option>
                <option value="PP1">PP1</option>
                <option value="PP2">PP2</option>
                <option value="PP3">PP3</option>
                <option value="PP4">PP4</option>
                <option value="PP5">PP5</option>
                <option value="PP6">PP6</option>
                <option value="PP7">PP7</option>
            </select>
            <br><br>
            Department: <br>
            <select name="dept">
                <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
                <option value="Team Leader">Team Leader</option>
                <option value="Post">Post</option>
                <option value="Test">Test</option>
                <option value="Stock Control">Stock Control</option>
            </select>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
        </form><br>
    </font>
</body>

</html>
```

When it does submit, everything is working as intended.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Update:  I have changed the following line:

```
var parent = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getParent();
```

to

```
var parent = SpreadsheetApp.openByID("IDhere");
```

This appears to have fixed it for some users.  I still have 3 users for whom some functions work, but others don't.  There are no longer any users who it all doesn't work for.